# Error starting mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache, python-3.x, mod-wsgi

When I run the start-server command on mod_wsgi-experess, I get this output:

```
Server URL      : http://localhost:8000/
Server Root     : /tmp/mod_wsgi-localhost:8000:0
Server Conf     : /tmp/mod_wsgi-localhost:8000:0/httpd.conf
Error Log       : /tmp/mod_wsgi-localhost:8000:0/error_log
httpd: Syntax error on line 2 of /tmp/mod_wsgi-localhost:8000:0/httpd.conf: module version_module is built-in and can't be loaded
```

The line 2 in the httpd.conf in the tmp folder that it is referring to says the following. It was automatically created by mod_wsgi:

```
LoadModule version_module '/usr/local/apache/modules/mod_version.so'
```

I am stumped. Any ideas how to get over this obstacle?

Comment: Probably better suitable for http://serverfault.com.

Answer (score 1):

I can change how the generated configuration is done, but can you indicate what Linux distribution the version of Apache you are using was supplied on, or if you compiled it yourself. Can you also provide the output in your question for running:

```
httpd -M
```

Change the 'httpd' in that command to whatever your Apache installation has called the main Apache HTTP server executable if it has been changed.

Right now the generated configuration expects that you are using an Apache installation which is built to use dynamic shared objects (DSO) for all Apache modules and doesn't statically compile in specific modules. It must also support dynamic loading of additional modules such as mod_wsgi.

I didn't contemplate that people would use an Apache version with statically compiled in modules, as doing that for the bulk of modules would defeat the purpose of trying to trim the memory size of Apache down by only loading what was needed.

In future if you have any questions about mod_wsgi it is recommended that the mod_wsgi mailing list be used. For an actual error/problem that looks to derive from mod_wsgi, use the issue tracker on the github mod_wsgi repository. StackOverflow in general is a poor place to ask about issues for mod_wsgi as StackOverflow isn't a forum and a large number of mod_wsgi questions get closed before they get answered because self styled moderators who know nothing about mod_wsgi can't actually see what the question posed may be is asking and wrongly close them as invalid when in a lot of cases there are simple answers if they actually knew the topic.

---

UPDATE 1

Further updates on this issue were done over on ServerFault.

- https://serverfault.com/questions/603729/error-starting-mod-wsgi

Comment: Hi Graham, thank you very much for your response. I am running Apache 2.2.21 on CentOS 5.1. The output of httpd -M is this: http://pastebin.com/eEgyrQgV  -- I am of course a total novice when it comes to Apache, so I appreciate your help. I will definitely look into the mailing list for the future.

Comment: That should be CentOS 5.10